# how to check item in QlistWidget and run function on the selected items in python pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have a python that display a GUI app that includes **qlistwidget**  that handles items and where the user can select these items by checking them and not select them using

```
itemSelectionChanged.connect.
```

I want once the user check the desired items the system save them in order to run another function on the CHECKED items.

like the image below :

[image]

here nothing is happen.

Until now i am able to save the checked items when the user select them.like this.

[image]

here the result displayed now is:

```
Checked items:  event_type, number_person
```

## QlistWidget:

```
   self.header_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
     self.header_list.setObjectName("listWidget")
     self.header_list.setMaximumWidth(120)
     self.header_list.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
     self.header_list.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.selectionChanged)
     self.horizontallLayout.addWidget(self.header_list)
```

## selectionChanged function :

```
def selectionChanged(self):
    checked = []
    for row in range(self.header_list.count()):
        item = self.header_list.item(row)
        if item.checkState():
            checked.append(item)
    print("Checked items: ", ", ".join(i.text() for i in checked))
    self.checked = [i.text() for i in checked]
```

so what is the event listener that can  replace **itemSelectionChanged** in order to save the result on just checking  the item and not selecting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check state of item views is stored in the model data, so when the state is changed the data is changed accordingly. QListWidget luckily already provides [`itemChanged(item)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemChanged):

> This signal is emitted whenever the data of item has changed.

This obviously means that the signal is emitted whenever *any* item is changed, and since you're going to check all items anyway you can keep the current function and just connect it to `itemChanged` instead of `itemSelectionChanged`.